# EF force reload of DB in Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I am using EF Code First. I am trying to seed my DB and refresh it in Azure every time I publish it. everyone suggests using this command, but it is not working. I've tried adding it to the `global.asax` and in the constructor of the context that inherits from `DBContext`, but no success:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyAPIContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyAPIContext>())
```

I do my seeding using:

```
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.UserName,
        new User
        {
            UserName = "John",
            Age = 21
        },
        new User 
        {
            UserName = "Mark",
            Age = 23
        },
```

and when I am ready to publish to my azure, I first update db:

```
update-database
```

and then I publish. for a test, I published it once with both users (John and Mark) and then the second time I remove the second user (Mark) before I redo update-database and publish, but it keeps remembering it after the 2nd publish

What's the deal? I want it to completely forget about previous records and just give me what I requested the last time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if still in Dev, deleting the db from azure is easiest option and then recreate it. Make sure to wait for azure until it confirms that it has finished creating your new DB.
Then trigger it so it runs the seed. That's what I've been doing the past 3 weeks and works great.